# AWS Cloudformation failing to acknowledge AutoScalingGroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, aws-cloudformation

While using CloudFormation to create EC2 instance along with an autoscaling group, I face the error:
`The following resource(s) failed to create: [WebsInstanceServerGroup].`

[image of CloudFormation Group output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD3TP.png)

The failure is seen while creating auto scaling group, but when I check the auto scaling group console, it says that the creation was 'successful.'  (The 'in-progress' deletion happens after a 15 minute time out value from CloudFormation).

[image of AutoScaling output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dED2w.png)

What could be the reason CloudFormation is not acknowledging that the AutoScale group is created successfully?

The error also says something about `WebInstanceServerGroup`, so I checked my template for that, but saw nothing suspicious.

```
"WebsInstanceServerGroup": {
  "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "AvailabilityZones": {
      "Fn::GetAZs": "AWS::Region"
    },
    "VPCZoneIdentifier": {
      "Ref": "WebsELBSubnetId"
    },
    "LoadBalancerNames": [
      {
        "Ref": "WebsELB"
      }
    ],
    "LaunchConfigurationName": {
      "Ref": "WebsEC2Instance"
    },
    "Cooldown": 300,
    "HealthCheckGracePeriod": 600,
    "HealthCheckType": "EC2",
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": {
          "Ref": "WebsInstanceName"
        },
        "PropagateAtLaunch": "true"
      },
      {
        "Key": "Service",
        "Value": {
          "Ref": "ServiceTag"
        },
        "PropagateAtLaunch": "true"
      }
    ],
    "MinSize": {
      "Ref": "ASGMin"
    },
    "DesiredCapacity": {
      "Ref": "ASGDesired"
    },
    "MaxSize": {
      "Ref": "ASGMax"
    }
  },
  "CreationPolicy": {
    "ResourceSignal": {
      "Count": {
        "Ref": "ASGMin"
      },
      "Timeout": "PT15M"
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if more information is required, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your EC2 instances in your autoscaling group are not sending [the required success signals](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-creationpolicy.html).

CloudFormation will wait for you to send `ASGMin` signals before considering your `WebsInstanceServerGroup` to be successfully created. So if `ASGMin` is set to 3, each of your 3 EC2 instances should send a signal.

To send the signal you can either use the [`cfn-signal`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-signal.html) helper, or [with the AWS CLI:](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/signal-resource.html)

```
aws cloudformation signal-resource \ 
  --stack-name {your stack name here} \
  --status SUCCESS \ 
  --logical-resource-id WebsInstanceServerGroup \ 
  --unique-id {the instance ID for the EC2 instance that is sending the signal}
```

Use this command at the end of your [User Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) script, when you consider your EC2 instance to be fully provisioned and ready to go.